# How google apps uses http in web?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, request, message, google-apps

I recently used messages app developed by google in my android phone.

https://messages.google.com/

You can use this app in web version by pairing with QR code.

I opened network tab in devtools and i can't find how this website receives messages in realtime. It's not sending Fetch or Xhr requests. and not using websocket.
But this website working on realtime with my phone.
It's not working with bluetooth or other wifi connections.
It's using just mobile data?

I interested is there any way to send http requests in chrome browser that works only for google apps?
And is it secure?

I opened devtools and i can't find anythis.
It's sending some requests to some urls but it's not data i am sending. They are same data always.